# Having multiple controllers for very same html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

hope you can help me with this one:

HTML:

```
    <div role="tabpanel" ng-controller="tabController">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="selectTab($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == $index}">
                <a data-target="#tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab {{tab.id}} <span ng-click="deleteTab($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-pills" ng-click="addTab()">
                <a aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">( + )</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <content ng-hide="counter === 0" ng-include="tabs[selectedTab].content">
        </content>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('tabController', function ($scope) {
    /** holds tabs, we will perform repeat on this **/
    $scope.tabs = [];

    // ContollerS for this => <content ng-hide="counter === 0" ng-include="tabs[selectedTab].content">
    $scope.currentTabController = null;

    // Hold controllers here;
    $scope.tabControllersList = [];

    $scope.counter = 0;
    /** Function to add a new tab **/
    $scope.addTab = function () {
        $scope.counter++;
    var tabController = new TabController();
    $scope.tabControllersList.push(tabController);
        $scope.tabs.push({ id: $scope.counter, content: tabController });
        $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs.length - 1; //set the newly added tab active. 
    }

    /** Function to delete a tab **/
    $scope.deleteTab = function (index) {
        $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1); //remove the object from the array based on index
    }

    $scope.selectedTab = 0; //set selected tab to the 1st by default.

    /** Function to set selectedTab **/
    $scope.selectTab = function (index) {
    // Add controller with all data and state.
    $scope.currentTabController = $scope.tabControllersList[index];
        $scope.selectedTab = index;
    }
});
```

So I want to have a separate controller for each tab (template for tabs the same - test.html), so when I switch tabs it would preserve data and chages in each of them. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Suggest you look at using `angular-ui-bootstrap` and get rid of `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I realized that in this case I need multiple *models*, not *controllers*. So *view* is the same, *controller* is the same, but I've added service to store and restore my *models* and on tab switch 
    $rootScope.$broadcast('onTabChanged', index);
I just swap to corresponding model.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question it sounds like you want to use a routeProvider.  In app.js list the routes like so:

```
var app= angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/presentation', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/presentation.html',
        controller: 'presentationCtrl'
      }).
      when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/presentation'
      });
  }]);
```

When you change views it will swap out part of your html page with the html located in the 'templateUrl' link.  You will need to put an `<div ng-view></div>` in your main html so Angular knows where you want to swap out the views.  When you change tags it will swap out the html and switch the controller based on the url.

You can refer to this tutorial for more information http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. But in this case (as I understand) data in other tabs will be lost. For example, we edited something in Tab1, then click Tab2 -> data in Tab1 is gone and so on. I'm trying to do something like this:

Comment: Ok, message is too long, so I've updated example above

Comment: What I'm trying to do -> save "state" of tabs and restore it when user will come back to tab. In ASP.NET there was ViewState, I would like to do the same in "angular way"